# In Unity3d using the FPS Controller, how can I keep a constant player speed when auto-walk forward using transform.forward?

Tags: unity-game-engine, controller

Using Unity3d First Person Controller, I want the player to move forward automatically in the direction the camera is looking at. It should behave the same as using the arrow keys, except I keep the arrow up key "pressed". I have this working in the script below, however the player slows down as he rotates the first-person camera away from the 0 degrees on the y-axis. When looking towards the 0 degrees on the y-axis, player speed is normal again.

How can I modify the script below so that the player always moves at a constant speed, no matter the camera rotation?

I set this script on the First Person Controller parent node:

```
public var head : GameObject;

private var motor : CharacterMotor;

// Use this for initialization
function Awake () {
    motor = GetComponent(CharacterMotor);
}

// Update is called once per frame
function Update () {
    // Retrieve a forward direction based on camera rotation
    var directionVector = transform.forward;
    directionVector.y = 0;
    directionVector.Normalize();

    // Apply the direction to the CharacterMotor
    motor.inputMoveDirection = transform.rotation * directionVector;
    motor.inputJump = Input.GetButton("Jump");
}

// Require a character controller to be attached to the same game object
@script RequireComponent (CharacterMotor)
@script AddComponentMenu ("Character/FPS Input Controller")
```

Comment: Why do you multiply by transform.rotation when your directionVector already comes from transform.forward?

Answer (score 0):

Multiply your movement for Time.deltaTime This time is the time between frames.

Example copy from http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html

```
function Update () {
    // Move the object 10 meters per second!
    var translation : float = Time.deltaTime * 10;
    transform.Translate (0, 0, translation);
}
```